# How to get the correct size of structure using ctypes in Python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, bit-fields

I declared a structure with bit fields, in C/C++, the size of struct is 5 as expected, while in Python, it's 6. (Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14))

```
from ctypes import *
class sHeader(LittleEndianStructure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [
            ("Field1", c_uint8, 4),
            ("Field2", c_uint16, 12),
            ("Field3", c_uint16, 12),
            ("Field4", c_uint16, 12)]

print(sizeof(sHeader))
```

Attached C++ code here:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct __attribute__((packed)) sHeader{
        uint8_t Filed1: 4;
        uint16_t Filed2: 12;
        uint16_t Filed3: 12;
        uint16_t Filed4: 12;
};

int main()
{
        std::cout << sizeof(sHeader) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the C++ code (there is no such language as C/C++) where you determined the size.

Comment: The expected size is 6, not 5. If you get 5, you're using a non-standard extension (I know gcc has one) and Python follows standard C.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I've attached the C++ code, thanks

Comment: @molbdnilo with "packed" attribute, the size is 5, Field1 & Field2 occupy 2 Bytes, Field3 & Field4 occupy 3 Bytes in total

Comment: @Kami Packed bitfields is a gcc extension, and ctypes does not support packed bitfields.

Comment: @molbdnilo From https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order, it says "By default, Structure and Union fields are aligned in the same way the C compiler does it. It is possible to override this behavior by specifying a _pack_ class attribute in the subclass definition. This must be set to a positive integer and specifies the maximum alignment for the fields. This is what #pragma pack(n) also does in MSVC."

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue29753, it's really a bug

Comment: On *Win* it's ***7***.

Comment: In Python 3.8 and Windows, Both C++ and Python agree: 7 for pack 1, and 8 for default packing.